# Wordpress - add external links to post thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm not sure if my title describes what I'm looking for accurately enough. Basically, I'm trying to replicate what has been done on this page, underneath each release: http://www.deadmau5.com/releases/

Now, I know I could just do it all manually every time a new release is added, but I want to make it as easy for the client to update as possible. Ideally, I want them to create a new page/post for their release, with custom fields for an Amazon and iTunes link. I'd want the featured image to appear on the parent page, with the Amazon & iTunes links underneath.

I've looked into the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for WP and it seemed to offer part of a solution, but not exactly fulfilling what I need it to do.

Can anyone suggest any plugins (or a combination of plugins) I could use? Or even any other way of doing this, which is going to make the process as easy as possible for my client to update?

Thanks.

Comment: Based in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505190/wordpress-add-external-links-to-post-thumbnail#comment20218404_14505283) of yours, did you look ACF's `Relationship` field?

Comment: @brasofilo The two links to accompany the post link should be external links though. I'm just struggling to get my head around how to have a post link AND 2 external links that are defined within that post, to display on a page which essentially shows ALL the posts thumbnails AND the relevant external links to iTunes and Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with custom fields.

Create a custom field that contains the link of where you want it to go. Then make the image a link with the href = to the custom field. Like so.

```
$link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_link', true);

echo '<a href="' . $link . '"> ' . the_post_thumbnail() . ' </a>';
```

Be sure to call your custom field `custom_link`.

Comment: But this does not totally do it. And how would that be written in form of a plugin?

Comment: Why do you need a plugin? Are you coding your own theme?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question on this would be how do I call the custom link if it's actually stored on another post? Because I need these to appear on one page, but there will be many of them. Do you know how I would give them their individual IDs? Because surely if they all have the same ID ie custom_link, then they will all display the same link?

Comment: @Chris: It's always better to have a plugin instead just some lines of code.

Comment: @hakre Even for 2 lines of code? Surely that's not very efficient?

Comment: the custom link is only relative to the post. So for each post generated the custom link would be the one you entered for that post.

Comment: @Chris: Even for a single line of code. I mean you need to interface with wordpress as this is a wordpress related question, so a plugin looks most easy to me, don't you think?

Comment: @hakre no sorry, i disagree. If you are building a custom theme, then a plugin that does what can be achieved in one line of code seems a bit of a long winded thing to do.

Comment: @Chris, sorry I'm not totally understanding where I should be putting this. I've inserted it into the text editor of a test wordpress page, but it's not displaying a link or anything at all. All that is displayed on the page is:

`ID, ‘custom_link’, true); ?>
‘ . the_post_thumbnail() . ‘ ‘;?>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who helped out. I found my solution here: http://millionclues.com/wordpress-tips/custom-image-and-link-for-each-post-using-custom-fields/